# How to prevent user pressing the button during the push segue animation?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I want to disable the button that triggers the push segue during the segue animation but enable it after the animation is finished. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you just set button.userInteractionEnabled = NO at the prepareForSegue. Then in the viewDidLoad of the new VC, you turn button.userInteractionEnabled = YES

Hope it help.

Comment: How can I enable the button in the old VC when I am in the new VC.

Comment: the question is that can you see the button after the push animation to new view controller or not? In your case if i'm not wrong, you tried to do something like split VC with side VC and content VC, so maybe you should consider to create contain VC which contains both VCs, in that case you will have the reference to the button.